# May I post an opinion posing a question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, off-topic

In a comment to this question, [How sacrosanct is the “source material” of Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/11365/254), Yuttadhammo wrote,

> This sounds a lot like opinion posing as a question... are you really looking for an answer, or are you just trying to promote your own ideas? I'm afraid the latter is more likely to lead to argumentation rather than conclusive answers, in which case this site is ill-suited for such activity.

Krishnaraj Rao (the OP) replied,

> Guilty as charged. I do of course hold many opinions, and I am of course trying to promote my own ideas, and looking for intelligent and well-reasoned arguments. Presumably, I am not alone in such an activity. and presumably, such an activity is at least as legitimate on this forum as posing questions to which there are definitive answers. Am I wrong in so presuming?

Yuttadhammo posted similar comments about two other questions yesterday,

- [Scientific Reincarnation Research](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/11357/254)

  > Are you really looking for an answer, or are you just looking to express your own opinion? I'm seeing more and more "questions" like this, and they don't really sound like questions to me. Maybe we need some meta discussion on the appropriateness of bias in questions.
- [Is The Kālāma Sutta Really Libertarian?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/11355/254)

  > Again, this sounds more like a preaching than an inquiry...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think forwarding opinions in questions are problematic (as long as there's a clear question and the opinions are there to give some background to it). I've seen many answers providing perspectives to support or refute them.

Maybe the problem is that the actual questions are not so clear, giving the impression that it is not an inquiry at all, but a statement?

Comment: How do you get a "right answer" in response to an opinion? Agree with it? I'm sorry, but this site seems less and less interesting to me as we move more towards the internet forum format. I'm probably going to resign as mod and not be as active as before... just prioritizing, personally.

Comment: I totally agree banthe that just an opinion posted as a question is not good. Maybe im trying to see questions where there aren't ones? I don't know... Im a little surprised that you see a movement towards a forum format. Not that i disagree, i just did not assess too much recent posts. I really really hope you don't lose interest though. Maybe you could write what you feel would be a better direction?

Answer (score 1):

Let anyone asked any type of questions. We should try only we likes. Let others answer what they interest. D..s are everywhere, let them bark.

Why we can't answer [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11380/equanimity-in-the-aghatavinaya-sutta)(equanimity-in-the-aghatavinaya-sutta)  yet?